# HOw to resolve Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons: CORS Network Failure URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request. WSO2APIm

Tags: http, https, request, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I got the error while hit API from WSO2 APIM dev and Publisher as admin access.

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:
CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

After that checked my tomal file everything configuratioin related CORS is used like

```
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
#allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false
```

other things I have tested also with API Level CORS.
through python if I hit python Endpoint works fine.

Only if I trying to from WSO2 APIM portal or by python script I got Error.
I cheked log file in its show :
27.107.154.35 - - [08/Nov/2023:13:03:06.748 +0000] "OPTIONS /API/uploadtext/1.0/upload_text/?title=sampl&email=vikas HTTP/1.1" - - "https://domain_name:9443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

HOw i can resolve this issue before that every thing works fine